# HDFS file matching error while creating tweet table in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, twitter, hive, flume

I am doing twitter sentiment analysis using flume, hadoop and hive. After creating the table with hive using this command :

```
hive -f tweets.sql
```

I get this error :

```
FAILED: SemanticException Line 3:17 Invalid path ''data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv'': No files matching path hdfs://localhost:9000/user/root/data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv
```

tweets.sql

```
--create the tweets_raw table containing the records as received from  Twitter
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Mytweets_raw (
id BIGINT,
created_at STRING,
source STRING,
favorited BOOLEAN,
retweet_count INT,
retweeted_status STRUCT<
text:STRING, 
user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,

entities STRUCT<
urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
text STRING,

user STRUCT<
screen_name:STRING,
name:STRING,
friends_count:INT,
followers_count:INT,
statuses_count:INT,
verified:BOOLEAN,
utc_offset:INT,
time_zone:STRING>,

in_reply_to_screen_name STRING

) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets';

-- create sentiment dictionary

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dictionary (
type string,
length int,
word string,
pos string,
stemmed string,
polarity string
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION '/data/dictionary';
-- loading data to the table dictionary

load data inpath 'data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv' INTO TABLE dictionary;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE time_zone_map (
time_zone string,  
country string
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/data/time_zone_map';

-- loading data to the table time_zone_map

load data inpath 'data/time_zone_map/time_zone_map.tsv' INTO TABLE       time_zone_map;
-- Clean up tweets

CREATE VIEW tweets_simple AS
SELECT
id, 
cast ( from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(concat( '2014 ',      substring(created_at,5,15)), 'yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss')) as timestamp) ts,
text,
user.time_zone 
FROM Mytweets_raw
;
CREATE VIEW tweets_clean AS
SELECT 
id,
ts,
text,
m.country 
FROM tweets_simple t LEFT OUTER JOIN time_zone_map m ON t.time_zone =  m.time_zone;
-- Compute sentiment

create view l1 as select id, words from Mytweets_raw lateral view  explode(sentences(lower(text))) dummy as words;

create view l2 as select id, word from l1 lateral view explode( words ) dummy as word ;

create view l3 as select 
id, 
l2.word, 
case d.polarity 
when  'negative' then -1
when 'positive' then 1 
else 0 end as polarity 
from l2 left outer join dictionary d on l2.word = d.word;

create table tweets_sentiment as select 
id, 
case 
when sum( polarity ) > 0 then 'positive' 
when sum( polarity ) < 0 then 'negative'  
else 'neutral' end as sentiment 
from l3 group by id;

-- put everything back together and re-name sentiments...

CREATE TABLE tweetsbi 
AS
SELECT  
t.*,
s.sentiment 
FROM tweets_clean t LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets_sentiment s on t.id = s.id;

-- data with tweet counts.....

CREATE TABLE tweetsbiaggr 
AS
SELECT 
country,sentiment, count(sentiment) as tweet_count 
FROM tweetsbi
group by country,sentiment;

-- store data for analysis......

CREATE VIEW A as select country,tweet_count as positive_response from  tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='positive';

CREATE VIEW B as select country,tweet_count as negative_response from tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='negative';

CREATE VIEW C as select country,tweet_count as neutral_response from tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='neutral';

CREATE TABLE tweetcompare as select A.*,B.negative_response as negative_response,C.neutral_response as neutral_response from A join B on A.country= B.country join C on B.country=C.country;

-- permission to show data in Excel sheet for analysis ....

grant SELECT ON TABLE tweetcompare to user hue;
grant SELECT ON TABLE tweetcompare to user root;
-- for Tableau or Excel
-- UDAF sentiscore = sum(sentiment)*50  / count(sentiment)
-- context n-gram made readable
```

hadoop fs -ls -R /data

```
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-03 17:10 /data/dictionary
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup     308921 2016-11-03 17:10 /data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-03 17:12 /data/time_zone_map
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup       3021 2016-11-03 17:12 /data/time_zone_map/time_zone_map.tsv
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-03 16:51 /data/tweets_raw
```

I want to know how it is taking the user/root/data path when it is not even mentioned in twitter.sql file.

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `/` at the beginning of the path.

So, the query would be

`load data inpath '/data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv' INTO TABLE dictionary;`

This applies to all the queries where you are loading data.

Let me know if this works.

Comment: It worked ! But now it just created one table and  it is showing " Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. MetaException(message:For direct MetaStore DB connections, we don't support retries at the client level.)". For more information, also the warehouse is the one that is already created and has the derby log. Is that the reason I am not able to delete tables that are being created now ? Please help me to fix this too.

Comment: can you let me know where the error happened? Run queries one by one and let me know where the error happened.

Comment: Actually, I think this is because I don't have the admin privileges to delete or modify tables. That is why even if they are created I cannot  I am currently running hive as root. Can you please tell me how to get the privileges as admin?

Comment: Chmod 777 for the warehouse directory

Comment: As us said to tell the exact problem after executing queries, I've again posted on this link. Please try, if you can help me fix this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40576637/execution-error-return-code-1-while-executing-query-in-hive-for-twitter-sentime