# Execution Error, return code 1 while executing query in hive for twitter sentiment analysis

Tags: json, twitter, mapreduce, hive, hadoop2

I am doing twitter sentiment analysis using hadoop, flume and hive. 
I have created the table using

```
hive -f tweets.sql
```

tweets.sql

```
--create the tweets_raw table containing the records as received from  Twitter
SET hive.support.sql11.reserved.keywords=false;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Mytweets_raw (
id BIGINT,
created_at STRING,
source STRING,
favorited BOOLEAN,
retweet_count INT,
retweeted_status STRUCT<
text:STRING, 
user:STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,

entities STRUCT<
urls:ARRAY<STRUCT<expanded_url:STRING>>,
user_mentions:ARRAY<STRUCT<screen_name:STRING,name:STRING>>,
hashtags:ARRAY<STRUCT<text:STRING>>>,
text STRING,

user STRUCT<
screen_name:STRING,
name:STRING,
friends_count:INT,
followers_count:INT,
statuses_count:INT,
verified:BOOLEAN,
utc_offset:INT,
time_zone:STRING>,

in_reply_to_screen_name STRING

) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
LOCATION '/user/flume/tweets';

-- create sentiment dictionary

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE dictionary (
type string,
length int,
word string,
pos string,
stemmed string,
polarity string
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE

LOCATION '/data/dictionary';
-- loading data to the table dictionary

load data inpath 'data/dictionary/dictionary.tsv' INTO TABLE dictionary;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE time_zone_map (
time_zone string,  
country string
)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/data/time_zone_map';

-- loading data to the table time_zone_map

load data inpath 'data/time_zone_map/time_zone_map.tsv' INTO TABLE       time_zone_map;
-- Clean up tweets

CREATE VIEW tweets_simple AS
SELECT
id, 
cast ( from_unixtime( unix_timestamp(concat( '2014 ',      substring(created_at,5,15)), 'yyyy MMM dd hh:mm:ss')) as timestamp) ts,
text,
user.time_zone 
FROM Mytweets_raw
;
CREATE VIEW tweets_clean AS
SELECT 
id,
ts,
text,
m.country 
FROM tweets_simple t LEFT OUTER JOIN time_zone_map m ON t.time_zone =  m.time_zone;
-- Compute sentiment

create view l1 as select id, words from Mytweets_raw lateral view  explode(sentences(lower(text))) dummy as words;

create view l2 as select id, word from l1 lateral view explode( words ) dummy as word ;

create view l3 as select 
id, 
l2.word, 
case d.polarity 
when  'negative' then -1
when 'positive' then 1 
else 0 end as polarity 
from l2 left outer join dictionary d on l2.word = d.word;

create table tweets_sentiment as select 
id, 
case 
when sum( polarity ) > 0 then 'positive' 
when sum( polarity ) < 0 then 'negative'  
else 'neutral' end as sentiment 
from l3 group by id;

-- put everything back together and re-name sentiments...

CREATE TABLE tweetsbi 
AS
SELECT  
t.*,
s.sentiment 
FROM tweets_clean t LEFT OUTER JOIN tweets_sentiment s on t.id = s.id;

-- data with tweet counts.....

CREATE TABLE tweetsbiaggr 
AS
SELECT 
country,sentiment, count(sentiment) as tweet_count 
FROM tweetsbi
group by country,sentiment;

-- store data for analysis......

CREATE VIEW A as select country,tweet_count as positive_response from  tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='positive';

CREATE VIEW B as select country,tweet_count as negative_response from tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='negative';

CREATE VIEW C as select country,tweet_count as neutral_response from tweetsbiaggr where sentiment='neutral';

CREATE TABLE tweetcompare as select A.*,B.negative_response as negative_response,C.neutral_response as neutral_response from A join B on A.country= B.country join C on B.country=C.country;

-- permission to show data in Excel sheet for analysis ....

grant SELECT ON TABLE tweetcompare to user hue;
grant SELECT ON TABLE tweetcompare to user root;
-- for Tableau or Excel
-- UDAF sentiscore = sum(sentiment)*50  / count(sentiment)
-- context n-gram made readable
```

While executing query

```
SELECT t.retweeted_screen_name, sum(retweets) AS total_retweets, count(*) AS tweet_count FROM (SELECT retweeted_status.user.screen_name as retweeted_screen_name, retweeted_status.text, max(retweet_count) as retweets FROM mytweets GROUP BY retweeted_status.user.screen_name, retweeted_status.text) t GROUP BY t.retweeted_screen_name ORDER BY total_retweets DESC LIMIT 10;
```

this error shows:

```
Query ID = root_20161114140028_852cb526-011f-4a25-95c8-8c6587a88759
Total jobs = 2
Launching Job 1 out of 2 
Number of reduce tasks not specified. Estimated from input data size: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/e70ec3c9-14c7-41e9-ad11-2d4528057e47_resources/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
at  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1309)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:288)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.getFileStatus(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:224)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestamps(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:93)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.filecache.ClientDistributedCacheManager.determineTimestampsAndCacheVisibilities(ClientDistributedCacheManager.java:57)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobResourceUploader.uploadFiles(JobResourceUploader.java:179)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.copyAndConfigureFiles(JobSubmitter.java:98)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:193)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:562)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$1.run(JobClient.java:557)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:557)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:548)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecDriver.execute(ExecDriver.java:433)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask.execute(MapRedTask.java:138)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:197)
at  org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:1858)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1562)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1313)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1084)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1072)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:232)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:183)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:399)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:776)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:714)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.FileNotFoundException(File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/e70ec3c9-14c7-41e9-ad11-2d4528057e47_resources/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar)'
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/e70ec3c9-14c7-41e9-ad11-2d4528057e47_resources/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.warehouse.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/lib/warehouse</value> 
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.metastore.local</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
  <value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=/usr/lib/warehouse/metastore_db;create=true </value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer</name>
  <value>256000000</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>hive.exec.reducers.max</name>
  <value>1009</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

However, I have added the jar file to hive, the same error shows :

```
ADD JAR file:///usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar;
```

Please help me fix this.

Comment: when you type "hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar", does the jar shows?

Comment: No, it says "No such file or directory:. But I thought that this jar is added only in hive, not in hdfs ? How to add it in hdfs ?

Comment: after adding the jar from local path also are you getting the error pointing to same hdfs location?

Comment: I tried this "ADD JAR hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAP‌​SHOT-jar-with-depend‌​encies.jar;"
But the jar does not exist on hdfs, so it shows again the FileNotFoundException. Do i have to add it on hdfs too?

Comment: it basically adds from the path you mentioned to collect the resource. if you give ADD JAR HDFS_PATH and if HDFS_PATH is empty, it shows the above exception

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
hadoop fs -put /usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAP‌​‌​SHOT-jar-with-depe‌​nd‌​encies.jar

ADD JAR hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAP‌​‌​SHOT-jar-with-depe‌​nd‌​encies.jar;
```

Comment: Actually, on hdfs, i dont have this /usr/lib/hive directory. I have /usr/lib/warehouse directory on hdfs where the tweet tables are created. So, can i add jar there inside /usr/lib ? Is it necessary to put into a hive directory only?

Comment: you can add to any hdfs path

Comment: I tried this. Now,  " hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/ "  shows json-serde-1.3.8-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar. But when i did " ADD JAR hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.8-SNAP‌​‌​SHOT-jar-with-depe‌​nd‌​encies.jar;" , it again says File does not exist. How to fix that ?

Comment: type "exit" and come out of the hive prompt, then try again

Comment: No, not working. I guess adding the jar from local path is not allowed. But I dont understand even when the jar is present, why does it say file does not exist? And when i add jar without using local, it says, jar not present in hdfs. Please if you can find a way to fix this.

Comment: we can add jar from local and hdfs using the above command. it should work. Another way is in hive-site.xml set property hive.aux.jars.path with value the serde jar and restart hive service

Comment: I tried to execute the query again. However, now it doesnt show the jar problem.  I have updated the error . Please can you tell whats wrong.

Comment: from where did you get this dependency jar ?

Comment: check if the fields type which when creating table gave as INT, but is  a string in JSON given. Plus I am not seeing table named "mytweets"

Comment: which version of hadoop hive are you using?

Comment: instead of that, try this jar http://www.congiu.net/hive-json-serde/1.3.6-SNAPSHOT/hdp23/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: I added the 1.3.6 version and sorry, I already changed it to mytweets name but forgot to update here. Versions are hive 2.1.0 and hadoop 2.7.0. On executing the query again,it said the localhost file not found error. So I added it through local host. But now  the error is " Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/tmp/e70ec3c9-14c7-41e9-ad11-2d4528057e47_resources/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar ".

Comment: And I added in hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar . I also checked it through ls command.

Comment: I have also updated the error. I am not getting why it keeps changing the location and gives exception from map reduce. Please, if you can help me fix this.

Comment: I also tried to execute this simple query, which is executing successfully.   SELECT user.screen_name, user.followers_count c from mytweets order by c desc;
Do you find anything wrong in the query?

Comment: if you are adding new jar, then close the hive prompt and login again, or it will take also the old added jar. Then try ADD JAR  hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-‌​with-dependencies.ja‌​r

Comment: Yes, I tried it after exiting . It's the same.I'm running the queries as root only.

Comment: share your hive-site.xml

Comment: Shared both hive-site.xml and mapred-site.xml. Please check it.

Comment: instead of adding jar run time. try adding in hive-site.xml as <property>
  <name>hive.aux.jars.path</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-‌​‌​with-dependencies.‌​ja‌​r</value>
</property> and restart hive services

Comment: I did all that. Again the same error " Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask. File does not exist: hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSH‌​OT-jar-‌​‌​with-depe‌​ndencies.‌​ja‌​r ". I think maybe the query is wrong because the other query executed perfectly !?

Comment: print me "hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSH‌​OT-ja‌​r-‌​‌​with-depe‌​nde‌​ncies.‌​ja‌​r"

Comment: When I did "hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSH‌​OT-ja‌​‌​r-‌​‌​with-depe‌​n‌​de‌​ncies.‌​ja‌​r", it said "No such file or directory".
When I did "hadoop fs -put /usr/lib/hive/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/" , it says "`hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar': File exists"

Comment: this is weird. check if the file is corrupted or try in different path

Comment: No actually when i do hadoop fs -ls /usr/lib , it shows the files . I guess, maybe hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib dont work. !?

Comment: can you share your core-site.xml and /etc/hosts

Comment: I have shared core-site and /etc/hosts. Please check it.

Comment: instead of localhost, give the hostip and restart all services

Comment: Actually, I have given local host because my ip address keeps on changing. Right now it would work fine, but later on it might change and process wont work. ? Also, as you already know , when i m starting hive, there are binding errors which might be the cause of this?

Comment: can you print the output of hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib

Comment: what do you get  when you type "sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9000"

Comment: For hadoop fs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib

Found 2 items
-rw-r--r--   1 root supergroup      79352 2016-11-14 15:22 hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
drwxr-xr-x   - root supergroup          0 2016-11-11 00:44 hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/warehouse

Comment: For sudo netstat -nlp | grep 9000
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9000              0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      17138/java

Comment: "hadoop fs -chmod 777 hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-‌​with-dependencies.ja‌​r" and try hive query

Comment: "chmod: `hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/lib/json-serde-1.3.6-SNAPSHOT-jar-‌​‌​with-dependencies.‌​ja‌​r': No such file or directory "
I am seriously not getting , how can it be possible. With ls it shows it is present and with other commands, it doesnt. I have just todays time , please if you can help.

Comment: try with hdfs://127.0.0.1:9000

Comment: Again No such file or directory. :(

Comment: try with sudo on front

Comment: I searched about it and found that some of these issues are caused when we do not run hive as an admin. I am running hive as root. Do you know how to do that? I guess maybe that will fix this up.

Comment: i dont know why it shows "No such file or directory" and "File exists" at the same time. Another approach is in  hive-site.xml, value of "hive.aux.jars.path" with local path instead of hdfs path

Comment: Sorry for later updation., I was working on it and now it shows a totally different issue. Please can you check on this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683844/datanode-error-while-executing-query-for-twitter-sentiment-analysis-on-hive