# ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am working on hadoop2.7.0 single node cluster with 4GB Ram and 40 GB HDD. While executing a word count example on Map reduce , it stopped after Running job...I've tried increasing the memory for container in yarn-site but still no luck.

Error

```
16/11/20 17:05:03 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
16/11/20 17:05:07 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
16/11/20 17:05:08 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
16/11/20 17:05:08 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1479631325160_0002
16/11/20 17:05:09 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1479631325160_0002
16/11/20 17:05:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1479631325160_0002/
16/11/20 17:05:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1479631325160_0002
```

This link shows :

```
YarnApplicationState:   ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>/nn1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>/dn1</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

core-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<configuration>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
  <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.reduces</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>  
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>  
  <value>512</value>
</property>
<property> 
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name> 
  <value>-Xmx410m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
  <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.map.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx204m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.reduce.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Xmx410m</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<property>
<name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
<value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property> 
<property>
  <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
  <value>256</value>
</property>
<property> 
  <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name> 
  <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property> 
  <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name> 
  <value>2048</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Check number of active nodes and is there any unhealthy nodes?

Comment: go to yarn web console http://localhost:8088 and check the memory and cores availability

Comment: Yes, it shows 0 Active nodes and 1 Unhealthy node .@Mahek

Comment: It shows 0 in both Memory Total and VCores total in Cluster Metrics. And in Scheduler Metrics, it shows <memory:1228, vCores:1> as minimum allocation and <memory:9830, vCores:32> as maximum allocation